# Cassandra replication - replicate some data but keep some local

Tags: cassandra, architecture, distributed, database, nosql

How do you configure Cassandra so that some tables are NOT replicated at all but others are?  Is this actually a good use case for Cassandra?

I have a group of customers (max. 50) that will all supply data on a daily basis (~50,000 records per customer per day, ~200 fields per record).  I need to pre-process the data to obfuscate sensitive information locally, then combine the data centrally for analysis and then allow reporting against the combined data set.  I am planning on each customer having a local Cassandra node for the raw data load (several flat files), but I don't want this replicated until the obfuscation is complete.  Can I do this with different tables spaces and replication factors?  The data can be keyed using customer ID as a PK, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a keyspace for the customer raw data with a replication factor of 1 and keep the raw data tables in there and then have the obfuscated data tables in a separate keyspace with a replication factor > 1.